# One-time mystery redirect from one of our pages

Tags: malware, apache, url-redirection

I'll make the explanation of the situation as thorough as I can, and the question is at the bottom.

Recently, we received a report from one of our users that, immediately after logging out of our application, he was suddenly redirected to a malware site.

There was activity in the address bar, and was forwarded in succession to two subsequent malware sites (as seen in his history). The final site he landed on was one of those pages that displays the obviously false claim that your computer has been compromised, and gives you a number to call.

I have the two URLs in question, but I won't post them here, as they're obviously nefarious.

Anyway, this leaves us with the puzzling question of what happened. The way I see it, there are two options:

1. The user's computer (an Apple, with no anti-virus software) is compromised
2. Our server did the redirect

The user said that he had the same issue a long time ago, but nothing like this recently. This is the first time in a long time that something like this has happened, and it only happened the one time on our site. It's tough to know if the issue the user had actually is the same issue as now.

This is the first, and so far only, report of this nature that we have had.

Some of the checks I did were:

- I checked the code in the area of the application relating to the action he performed, and there seemed to be nothing amiss.
- I looked at the source of the website just before performing the last action the user did, to see if there was any odd JavaScript. It all checked out.
- I checked the "live" version of the application against an older repository, and nothing out of the ordinary
- I grepped the entire web directory looking for headers, PHP eval statements, header calls and base_64_decodes (possible PHP redirects), and the actual malware URLs, and found nothing suspicious.
- I searched all the Apache config files for any suspicious redirects, and didn't find anything.

I've also tried repeating the action he performed (using a similar environment to his) many times, without replicating the redirect. He also did it again later, and didn't receive the same problem.

Obviously, whether it is on his side or ours, it is not consistent.

The question is: have I missed anything obvious to check? Could there be an Apache / server level compromise doing this, for example?

Comment: I've seen authentication mechanisms that have a redirect option after the authentication process was successful. This is done for the user's convenience, if a user points to a specific location in a web application but is no longer authenticated the login mechanism redirects the user back to that specific point. Does this apply to your application as well? If so, can it be manipulated? It sounds like you have an open redirect. That's just one thought.

Comment: @Jeroen-ITNerdbox Thank you for the comment. At first, I was thinking it might have been something like that. There is a redirect happening, both on login, and on logout, but neither of them are open (the destinations are fixed and hard-coded). I don't think they could be manipulated, certainly not from the client side.

Comment: I think there's a third option: the user is being MitM'd. Do you know anything about how he's accessing your site (e.g. public wifi, HTTPS)?

Comment: @SCruz Possible MITM. Also there may be Trasparent proxies involved...https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server#Transparent_proxy

Comment: It is quite common to have malicious redirects in .htaccess files on compromised hosts. The use of random to trigger the redirect is also a common technique deployed to delay detection. You can look for these redirects server side by looking for 301/302/307 responses in your server logs

Comment: Are there any ads on your site? Ad networks are another common vector for this kind of attack.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your responses. Lot's to consider.

@grc I believe accessing from a home router - however, it's through HTTPS, which might mitigate the possibility of a man in the middle here? Is there a way an unfocused MitM attack such as a redirect could occur when the client and server are connected with SSL?

Comment: @grc I believe accessing from a home router - however, it's through HTTPS, which might mitigate the possibility of a man in the middle here? Is there a way an unfocused MitM attack such as a redirect could occur when the client and server are connected with SSL?

Comment: @Sravan The IP address under which his activity shows in our logs is from his own (valid) IP address. I'm not sure if that has a bearing on whether it could have been an open proxy between us.

Comment: @wiregoul We don't allow .htaccess files. There were a few legacy ones scattered around, but I checked them all to be sure, and then deleted them all. I also checked the Apache directives in the VirtualHosts, and they seemed okay.

Comment: @Alfred Armstrongs No ads!

Comment: do you have any non ssl imports? (javascript, css, iframes)

Comment: I doubt the MitM proposal, as it seems like a fairly innocuous attack to perform comparatively to what could be accomplished.  But for lack of a better theory, are you sending the HSTS header in server responses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> have I missed anything obvious to check?

It seems to me like you've done quite a bit of analysis local to you, so you've probably missed nothing *obvious*, but there are some *subtle* things you might have missed. As supplement to this answer I'll explain multiple attacks that could be so subtle and virtually out of your control that it's possible for any insecure website that uses a hostname and/or client that uses an insecure DNS and HTTPS configuration (i.e. any that use plain old HTTP and don't rely explicitly upon DNSSEC) to fall victim, and the attackers can sometimes virtually infeasible to actively shut down. I'll also describe how you can prevent these *subtle* attacks, in case you missed the subtle hints in this paragraph.

---

> Could there be an Apache / server level compromise doing this, for example?

I guess you could call an insecure configuration a *compromise*, especially if it's intentionally configured to be insecure there by an attacker. The most dangerous of these misconfigurations could be present in the form of rogue administration accounts on a server, rogue software installation, rogue certificate authorities, so on and so forth. Antivirus software may not detect all *compromises* (misconfigurations), and it's important to consider them in light of a *security regime* which consists of multiple components, not just antivirus software.

You should keep all of your software up-to-date, particularly Apache, your OS and particularly web browsers as there are attacks which target specific versions of Apache, your OS and web browsers, and I'd suggest that all of those kinds of attacks are commonly used. The ones described here, however, are less likely to be commonly observed, owing to their risk factors or the level of skill required to reproduce them in ratio to the amount of maturity one must possess to establish that skill, and *much* less likely to be detected by antivirus software owing to their existence as *flaws in configuration* rather than as *malware*. For some reason, there's a distinction between these two concepts. I think there shouldn't be.

Simply put, the internet is held in balance by the thin layer of ice which is the fact that the mature, highly experienced users of the internet (the top 1%, if you like) haven't decided to wage war against everyone on the planet. Sure, there may be some Russian and Chinese hackers who ruin it, but those malicious IP subnets can be blocked by firewalls and DNSBLs, their scans crippled by tarpits, so on and so forth.

---

The first attack to consider is as simple as a service provider filtering their customers traffic. In doing so, they could quite easily set up a phishing site over the top of yours, or inject some Javascript which redirects the user. Such an attack would be blatantly obvious, and indefensible in court, nonetheless you might still observe this.

This could occur anywhere between your server and your client, even on your own (or their own) routers as we'll inspect later. For now, we'll focus on the routers that exist between your network and your clients network which neither of you own. This could include proxy servers and nameservers.

Typical ISPs run at least a caching DNS resolver for the clients to reduce congestion along the up-stream network, and that is itself a form of filtering. Some might even run proxy software which compresses media files and/or caches static HTML pages to reduce bandwidth for clients. Each of these *caches* has the potential to be tampered with, internally or externally.

Internally, a malicious employee at an ISP could likely corrupt the local DNS cache to give the client a different IP for your hostname, or corrupt a proxy to send a different page (or perhaps a different version of jquery). That'd be very blatant, incredibly stupid attack as the risk of being caught in this highly illegal attack increases as attacks are repeated. Nonetheless, if you're an American citizen, best of luck getting a maliciously hosted public proxy hosted in China taken down...

Besides, without some source code for the page allegedly hosted by you that your client ended up on, there's no way you could prove that an upstream provider somewhere between your client and your server has interfered with traffic. You need to find that proof if you want to find the source, or solve the problem if you want to solve the problem. That source code is just one source of information you'd need to obtain to track down the culprit.

When a browser is sent a signed page from a server, it will contact some *certificate authority* to ensure the certificate that signed the page legitimately came from the server that it's apparently from. The responses sent by a certificate authority are themselves signed with keys which are generally hard-configured into your OS/network configuration/browser and thus *fraudulently forging* such a response (which we'll cover later with respect to *other attacks*) would be even less practical than *somehow encouraging the end-users to overtly install a rogue certificate authority signature (like convincing them to install malicious software)*. There's no doubt that a hardened SSL configuration at both ends (server and end user) will prevent all of the attacks I describe here.

---

As it turns out, even home routers nowadays have their own caching resolvers, once again to reduce traffic congestion on the up-stream network. Thus, a malicious machine on the same private network might have no problems infecting your router and corrupting its DNS caching resolver.

Cue the cellular attacks:
 - A typical consumer-grade cell-phone internet user is technically also on a private network. Indeed, the cell router may be misconfigured to allow clients to attack other clients. The routers are 3G/HSPDA+ enabled, introducing the potential for numerous electromagnetic attacks which tend to be encrypted, but I suppose if a client enables roaming they might not necessarily know which towers they're connecting to or who runs those "towers", leading to a potential for MITM attacks which are similar to some other wireless network attacks. 
 - The typical cell-phone client who has external access via some other provider can launch another style of attack against all other users of that mobile internet carrier within the local area (could be as vast as state region) and... any insecure website... could be yours, could be all, might be effected. What's important is that the content be unencrypted end-to-end. This client has everything they need to trigger the ISPs caching resolver to send a request for a zone (you can basically think of this as a *domain*, if you're uninitiated), and to forge thousands of fake responses for the request which will all beat any legitimate response to the target.

It's important to realise that a secure implementation of signed, domain-verified encryption such as a hardened HTTPS configuration will cripple all of the attacks I describe here, as I previously explained.

---

Attacks against DNS themselves aren't few and far between. There is a technique known as "bitsquatting", where-by a nefarious domain is registered which differs in *just one bit* from the target domain. For example, an attacker targeting an insecure HTTP configuration hosted by stac`k`exchange.com might register the domain stac`i`exchange.com. Notice the difference between `k` and `i` is only *one bit*. This targets any routers which might have RAM errors that occasionally flip that bit.

Nonetheless, a user connecting via a hardened HTTPS configuration will almost certainly be warned about invalid certificates if the attacker can't work out what their targets private key is in order to make the content appear legitimate. This would be present as a clue from your users report, if he/she said "The browser said the certificate was invalid", for example.

---

Those last few attacks make it *really* difficult to blame a server, client or router anywhere between. To prove *who* (perhaps inadvertently) tampered with the traffic, you'll need to call administrators for *each router between yourself and the client* and see what they have in their caches. This introduces extra higher-level challenges in your quest to track down the potential issue. You may be quickly shut down by any foreign ISPs or authority who you approach to track this down. They may speak a different language (such as Russian or Chinese), they may not have laws that criminalise these behaviours, they may behave in a hostile manner towards you because of your race and they may not want to admit insecurities in their own network.

However, there are things you can do to protect yourself from this specific attack, and as they say prevention is better than cure. Most significantly, you should try to at least gracefully upgrade users to a secure SSL connection. Additionally, if you do happen to get a call from a client and while you're on the phone they can repeatedly reproduce the issue, consider instructing them to take steps such as clearing the local DNS, proxy, and browser caches, one at a time, checking to see if the symptoms disappear each time. This will tell you whether the clients network (not just one computer) is at fault or not. Additionally, if you're not already using a DNSSEC-enabled nameserver for your zone, you probably should consider migrating to one, as that'll eliminate similar attacks for other non-HTTP services.

For the meantime, I'm going to assume HTTP is the service you want to harden, and since you can't guarantee users will harden their DNS configuration you should rely upon browsers and OSes hardening their HTTPS configurations instead, and thus try to upgrade your users connections to HTTPS where possible.

---

Regarding the clients computer having no antivirus on OS X, this is not enough information to determine whether the clients network is to blame. OS X isn't exactly insecure; sure, they have the occasional vulnerability, but those tend to get patched as with any OS. Where clients go wrong here is when they don't apply the automatic updates or patches necessary to keep their system secure, or they install rogue software themselves. In this case, default Apple configurations nowadays use a similar *certificate authority* technique to ensure binaries are *signed* by Apple, or else pop up a warning to the user (or flat out refuse to execute the program). Apple can, of course, revoke the legitimacy of a signature at their own discretion, and they rely largely upon this to protect their users against malware. It's a good system which package managers on Linux tend to also follow.

What's scariest of all is that there appears to be no antivirus software available to scan the software that executes on your printer. Thus, some printers might be capable of attacking the users of the networks they're installed on, or even external networks.

---

In summary, these are the things you might want to consider:

- Keep your computer software up-to-date, including your OS, any antivirus software which might or might not be necessary, and *particularly* any browser software. This goes for all internet users, yourself included, though for you there are some pieces of software you might want to consider: tarpits and DNSBL integration software being a few.
- Be wary of browser extensions, as these may themselves tamper with pages or introduce vulnerabilities.
- Host your zone on a DNSSEC-enabled nameserver. Just do it, mate. Don't ummm and arrr about it. This is like SPF for email servers; if you don't do it, you'll eventually become a victim of an attack.
- Configure your servers to gracefully upgrade your clients to SSL, at the very least.

Comment: Sorry I missed this somehow when originally posting this, but thank you very much for the detailed response.

Answer (score 2):

The first place I would be looking to find what my server has done is in my logs. A redirect issued as a header would show there (but not a meta or javascript redirect).

At least this would tell me which code to audit.